# How to customize Google charts from code using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I am using **google charts** for my asp.net web application. I have successfully got the chart working in my application. But I want to know how to add animation, change the color of the column chart from code. In javascript I know it can be done using  below **option** -

```
var options = {
width: 400,
height: 240,
title: 'Sample Data',
colors: ['#e0440e', '#f6c7b6'],
is3D:true         
};
```

I tried calling the same in c# using string builder but chart itself doesnot load. Here is my code-

```
private void BindCourseChart()
 {
   //to bind course chart
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   try
     {
       dt = GetData_Course();

       str.Append(@"<script type=text/javascript> google.load( *visualization*, *1*,        {packages:[*corechart*],callback:drawChart});

       function drawChart() {
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       data.addColumn('string', 'Title');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Users enrolled');
       **//Here I am adding role=style for customizing**
       data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
       data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");");

       for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
       {
         str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]            ["Title"].ToString() + "');");
         str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["MenteeCount"].ToString() + ") ;");

       }

       str.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('course_div'));");
       str.Append(" chart.draw(data, {width: 650, height: 300, title: 'Course Enrollment', color:#0092CB,");
       str.Append("hAxis: {title: 'Course Title', titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'}}");

       str.Append("}); }");
       str.Append("</script>");
       lt_course.Text = str.ToString().TrimEnd(',').Replace('*', '"');
 }
```

Can anyone help me in this regard how to add colors,or animation to column charts .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I take you use the "outdated" Winforms approach? This is a lot of code for something you could "just do" in ASP.NET with the MVC framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since David addressed the color issue, I'll tackle the animations.  Animating the chart on first draw is a bit complicated; you have to draw it once with a zero'd out data set, and then draw it again with the real data set.  Here's some javascript (that you can add to your string builder, replacing the chart creation and drawing lines) that will animate the chart:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, {
    sourceColumn: 1,
    calc: function () {return 0;}
}, 2]);

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('course_div'));
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart.draw(data, {
        width: 650,
        height: 300,
        title: 'Course Enrollment',
        color: '#0092CB',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Course Title',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'green'
            }
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000
        }
    });
});
chart.draw(view, {
    width: 650,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Course Enrollment',
    color: '#0092CB',
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Course Title',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'green'
        }
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```

**[Edit - attempt at C# example]**

```
private void BindCourseChart()
{
    //to bind course chart
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        dt = GetData_Course();

        str.Append(@"
<script type=text/javascript>
google.load( *visualization*, *1*, {packages:[*corechart*], callback:drawChart});

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Title');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Users enrolled');
    **//Here I am adding role=style for customizing**
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
    data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");
        ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]            ["Title"].ToString() + "');");
            str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["MenteeCount"].ToString() + ") ;");
        }

        str.Append(@"
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, {
        sourceColumn: 1,
        calc: function () {return 0;}
    }, 2]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('course_div'));
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        chart.draw(data, {
            width: 650,
            height: 300,
            title: 'Course Enrollment',
            color: '#0092CB',
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Course Title',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    color: 'green'
                }
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
    });
    chart.draw(view, {
        width: 650,
        height: 300,
        title: 'Course Enrollment',
        color: '#0092CB',
            hAxis: {
            title: 'Course Title',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'green'
            }
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000
        }
    });
}
</script>
    ");

    lt_course.Text = str.ToString().TrimEnd(',').Replace('*', '"');
}
```

Comment: From javascript i know how to do, but from code C# i am not getting how to do.. If i add options with string builder chart itself is not displaying. can u provide any example using c#..thanks

Comment: My C# is rusty, so this might not be right, but I'll try adding an example to my answer that you can try.

Answer (score 4):

If interested, I made a Google Chart class awhile back that I've used in a few projects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Google
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for GoogleChart
    /// </summary>
    public class GoogleChart
    {
        // Fields
        private string data = "";
        private string javascript;

        // Properties
        public string elementId { get; set; }

        public int height { get; set; }

        public string title { get; set; }

        public int width { get; set; }

        // ChartTypes
        public enum ChartType
        {
            BarChart,
            PieChart,
            LineChart,
            ColumnChart,
            AreaChart,
            BubbleChart,
            CandlestickChart,
            ComboChart,
            GeoChart,
            ScatterChart,
            SteppedAreaChart,
            TableChart
        }

        // Methods
        public GoogleChart()
        {
            this.title = "Google Chart";
            this.width = 730;
            this.height = 300;
            this.elementId = "chart_div";
        }

        public void addColumn(string type, string columnName)
        {
            string data = this.data;
            this.data = data + "data.addColumn('" + type + "', '" + columnName + "');";
        }

        public void addRow(string value)
        {
            this.data = this.data + "data.addRow([" + value + "]);";
        }

        public string generateChart(ChartType chart)
        {
            this.javascript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script>";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart']});";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "function drawChart() {";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + this.data;
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "var options = {";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "'title': '" + this.title + "',";
            object javascript = this.javascript;
            this.javascript = string.Concat(new object[] { javascript, "'width': ", this.width, ", 'height': ", this.height, "};" });
            string str = this.javascript;
            this.javascript = str + "var chart = new google.visualization." + chart.ToString() + "(document.getElementById('" + this.elementId + "'));";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "chart.draw(data, options);";
            this.javascript = this.javascript + "} </script>";
            return this.javascript;
        }
    }

}
```

You can then use it by doing the following:

```
private void GenerateQuickStats()
{
    GoogleChart chart = new GoogleChart();
    chart.title = "Quick Stats";
    chart.width = 250;
    chart.height = 200;
    chart.addColumn("string", "Year");
    chart.addColumn("number", "Value");
    chart.addColumn("number", "Profit");
    chart.addRow("'2014', 2000, 1000");
    // asp literal
    ltChart.Text = chart.generateChart(GoogleChart.ChartType.ColumnChart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing quotation marks around your color...

At the end of this line:

```
str.Append(" chart.draw(data, {width: 650, height: 300, title: 'Course Enrollment', color:#0092CB,");
```

you need apostrophes around the hex color:

```
str.Append(" chart.draw(data, {width: 650, height: 300, title: 'Course Enrollment', color:'#0092CB',");
```

If that doesn't work, compare the javascript that your app generates with your manually created code.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked by adding colors:['#0092CB'].I am trying to add animation when the column chart first time loads but no luck ..any idea how it can be done from C#